# Include python files within subdirectory with cxfreeze

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze a python project into an exe. When I open the command prompt in the directory "Notifier" and run `cxfreeze notifier/main.py`, the project compiles correctly. I'm trying to get the same result from in setup.py so that when I run `python setup.py build_exe`, an exe with its dependencies is created just like before.

This is the directory structure:

```
Notifier/
|notifier/
|- __init__.py
|- main.py
|- sender.py
|- request.py
|setup.py
```

When I run `python setup.py build_exe`, I notice that under `Missing Modules:` it has `sender imported from main__main__`. And when I run main.exe from `Notifier/build/exe.win32-2.7`, the following error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "notifier/main.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sender
```

Here's my setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import requests.certs

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files': [(requests.certs.where(), 'cacert.pem')]
    }
}

setup(
    name='Notifier',
    version='0.1',
    license='MIT',
    author='David Corbin',
    #install_requires=['requests', 'websocket', 'cx_Freeze'],
    options=options,
    executables=[Executable("groupmenotifier/main.py")]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a file named `__init__.py` in the `notifier` folder.

Comment: @JasperXu What should be in the `__init__.py` file? I create the file in `notifier` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the `groupmenotifier/` directory to the search path so that cxfreeze can find and use it.

```
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"\\groupmenotifier")
```